# Why should one unit test MVC routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I see that people have ask more specific questions, but mine is broad, why should one test any routes at all? where does the benefit of this really shine? Thanks!

PS currently doing this in .Net C# MVC 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just my 2¢ to a very subjective question:

Because by unit testing your routes, a single key combination (that will run the unit tests) allows you to verify whether they behave as expected in contrast to running through your entire application and manually testing them by wasting enormous time and by potenatially forgetting to manually test some of the edge cases. Also when some other developer inherits the code base and starts modifying it, it is much easier for him to run this same key combination (that runs the unit tests) and get instant feedback whether his modifications didn't have some impact on the existing functionality rather than manually going through the entire application and clicking through all the links and stuff.

And from practical point of view I use [MvcContrib TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper#Routes) to unit test my routes.

Comment: That's a good description of why you'd want unit testing, but it doesn't answer the specific case of why you'd want to unit test your routes...

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, it's the same reason :-) You prefer to hit a single key combination to verify whether the code you have written is correct rather than going through your entire application. And of course, the more complex your application, the more time you waste to go through it, whereas the key combination stays the same :-)

Comment: But why should you test the routes *at all*?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, because it's a code that you, as a developer, write. And you know, nobody's perfect. We all make mistakes. So we'd better test our code, don't you think? Of course you might say, why care about testing my code, I write perfect code. Well, then I have nothing to say. You write perfect code and that's really great for you. I know that personally I make mistakes when writing code so I prefer to take guarantees. I also want to ease the task of people taking over my code and by looking at the unit test they know how this code is supposed to work. As I said: a subjective question.

Comment: There's no need to be patronising. I agree with you about unit-testing in general. However, you can't always unit test everything. What makes it valuable to test routes? How much effort is it? How likely are they to suffer from regressions? What kind of mistakes does unit testing the routes help with? If the cost-benefit analysis doesn't work out, it's probably better to spend test effort on something else. So, again: why unit test your MVC routes?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, I am not patronising anyone. I am just speaking from my personal experience and what I do in my projects. As I already said: **this is a subjective question**, so we can be talking here until the next year without being constructive. I gave my 2 cents, you gave yours. I respect your opinion if you think that there's no need to unit test routes. That's why subjective questions normally are not welcome on SO. Because they spark such completely useless and not constructive debates. Neither I will convince you, neither you will convince me. Wish you a Happy New Year tomorrow.

Comment: sorry I haven't had a chance to reply until now, but by testing routes, you are really testing that a controller and method exist. So I just want to verify, the route tests will essentially only break if someone changes the naming, parameters of a route, or if they've been deleted all together correct?  

I agree that unit tests are useful but they need meaning behind them, so I am trying to give meaning to my route testing :)